# Parse xsi:type in XML with ElementTree in Python

Tags: python, xml, api, soap, elementtree

I'm trying to connect to a RESTful API and I'm hacing problems when building the XML request, for that I'm using Elementree library.

I have an example of the XML I have to send in the request. From that example a build a model and then write the different attributes by code. But  the output XML is not exactly like the example I was given and I'm unable to connect to the API.

This is the example I have:

```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <GetLoc xmlns="http://abc/Getloc">
        <request>
          <Access>
            <string xmlns="http://bcd/Arrays"></string>
          </Access>
          <Details xsi:type="Request">
            <Postcode ></Postcode >
          </Details>
          <UserConsent>Yes</UserConsent>
        </request>
      </GetLoc>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

This is my code:

```
tree = ET.parse('model.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
ns = {'loc':'http://abc/Getloc',\
        'arr':http://bcd/Arrays',\
        'soapenv':'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', \
        'xsi':"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", \
         xsd': "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"}

tree.find('.//arr:string', ns).text = 'THC'
tree.find('.//Postcode ', ns).text = '15478'
```

This is the output XML (SOAP):

```
  <ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://abc/Getloc" xmlns:ns2="http://bcd/Arrays" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:GetLoc >
        <ns1:request>
          <ns1:Access>
            <ns2:string>THC</ns2:string>
          </ns1:Access>
          <ns1:Details xsi:type="Request">
            <ns1:Postcode >15478</ns1:Postcode >
          </ns1:Details>
          <ns1:UserConsent>Yes</ns1:UserConsent>
        </ns1:request>
      </ns1:GetLoc >
    </ns0:Body>
  </ns0:Envelope>
```

With the example (first above) I have no problem when connecting to the API. However with the second one I get and error:

```
 " status="Service Not Found.  The request may have been sent to an invalid URL, or intended for an unsupported operation." xmlns:l7="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>"
```

Both XML are sent to the same URL with the same headers and auth. I see both XML equivalent so I was expecting same behavior. I don't understand why it isn't working.

EDIT: The output XML needs to be like

```
<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://abc/Getloc" xmlns:ns2="http://bcd/Arrays" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ns0:Body>
          <ns1:GetLoc >
            <ns1:request>
              <ns1:Access>
                <ns2:string>THC</ns2:string>
              </ns1:Access>
              <ns1:Details xsi:type="ns1:Request">
                <ns1:Postcode >15478</ns1:Postcode >
              </ns1:Details>
              <ns1:UserConsent>Yes</ns1:UserConsent>
            </ns1:request>
          </ns1:GetLoc >
        </ns0:Body>
      </ns0:Envelope>
```

But I don't know hoy to change the code to get: **xsi:type="ns1:Request"**

Comment: I found a solution making my own parser. I got the info from here: http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm

Comment: Can you please add an answer? I'm sure it would help future visitors.

Comment: Done @DanielHaley, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution myself.

The solution is in [here](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm) (an incredibly complete article), since I was already using ElementTree. You may find other solutions like using [lxml](https://lxml.de/3.8/index.html) library.

So, for ElementTree I just need to use my own parser instead of the standard ***ElementTree.parse('file.xml')***.

*The xsi attribute name is handled by the parser, but the parser doesn’t know that the attribute happens to contain a qualified name as well, so it leaves it as is. To be able to handle such a format, you can use a custom parser that knows how to handle certain attributes and elements, or keep track of the prefix mapping for each element.
To do the latter, you can use the iterparse parser, and ask it to report “start-ns” and “end-ns” events. The following snippet adds an ns_map attribute to each element which contains the prefix/URI mapping that applies to that specific element:*

```
def parse_map(file):
    events = "start", "start-ns", "end-ns"
    root = None
    ns_map = []
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(file, events):
        if event == "start-ns":
            ns_map.append(elem)
        elif event == "end-ns":
            ns_map.pop()
        elif event == "start":
            if root is None:
                root = elem
            elem.ns_map = dict(ns_map)
    return ET.ElementTree(root)
```

Comment: Please don't just link to an article. If the link stops working, this answer becomes completely useless. Show us code and explain why `parse_map` solved the problem.